# Python Grpc deserialze ByteString

Tags: python, deserialization, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python

After a request to GRPC-java server, in the Python client I get the object of the following type:

```
<class 'GetInsertService_pb2.CountResponse'>
```

It has the following methods:

```
['ByteSize', 'Clear', 'ClearExtension', 'ClearField', 'CopyFrom', 'DESCRIPTOR', 'DiscardUnknownFields', 'Extensions', 'FindInitializationErrors', 'FromString', 'HasExtension', 'HasField', 'IsInitialized', 'ListFields', 'MergeFrom', 'MergeFromString', 'ParseFromString', 'RegisterExtension', 'SerializePartialToString', 'SerializeToString', 'SetInParent', 'UnknownFields', 'WhichOneof', '_CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile', '_SetListener', '__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '_extensions_by_name', '_extensions_by_number', 'result']
```

Proto looks like this:

```
message UIDRequest {
    string uid = 1;
}

//
message CountResponse {
    string result = 1;
}

service GetInsertService {
    rpc get(UIDRequest) returns (CountResponse);

}
```

My java server implementation:

```
public class GetInsertServiceImpl
    extends GetInsertServiceGrpc.GetInsertServiceImplBase {

  @Override
  public void get(
      GetInsertServiceOuterClass.UIDRequest request,
      StreamObserver<GetInsertServiceOuterClass.CountResponse> responseObserver) {

    RawKVClient dbClient = SingletonDB.getInstance().client;

    ByteString res =
        dbClient.get(ByteString.copyFrom(String.valueOf(request.getUid()), Charsets.UTF_8));
    GetInsertServiceOuterClass.CountResponse response =
        GetInsertServiceOuterClass.CountResponse.newBuilder()
            .setResult(res.toString())
            .build();
    // Use responseObserver to send a single response back
    responseObserver.onNext(response);

    // When you are done, you must call onCompleted.
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
  }
```

That's my client py code:

```
    channel_grpc = grpc.insecure_channel('ip:port')
    stub = GetInsertService_pb2_grpc.GetInsertServiceStub(channel_grpc)
    msg_count = stub.get(GetInsertService_pb2.UIDRequest(uid=user_id))
```

So the `msg_count` has a value string `result` inside.

But when I do:
- `msg_count.SerializeToString()` I get `b'\n\x1c<ByteString@3ffef3bb size=2>'`
- `msg_count.result` returns `result: "<ByteString@3ffef3bb size=2>"`

How to get the actual value (like '14' instead of `<ByteString@3ffef3bb size=2>`)?

Comment: Could you post your server implementation, I think it returns the string `<ByteString@3ffef3bb size=2>`

Comment: Just attempt to ask you print out the `res.toString()` :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your server might be returning the string `<ByteString@3ffef3bb size=2>`, not your client code.

Also from your comment, in java server use `res.toStringUtf8()` to apply utf8 encoding.